# <nul set /p Text Output approach has a weird quirk with Commands and Pipeline

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, windows-server-2019

Summary: Does the `set /p` command ***force*** the `CMD interpreter` to evaluate a Pipeline, even if it's escaped?  Is it possible to avoid this?

### Further Reading

Consider the following line from a batch file. The purpose of the code below is to output `Echo F | Xcopy /Y 'FilePath1' 'FilePath2'` to the log file.

#### This fails... sort of

```cmd
<nul (set /p "Lineout=Echo F ^| Xcopy /Y '%~1' '%~2'") >>%log%
```

I successfully get a string output to `%log%` as expected, but in the batch file's console, I get `Invalid Parameters` warnings for each time this is listed.  I am assuming the issue is from the `|` pipeline somehow invoking the Xcopy command, but I don't understand why it's doing this, even though I've escaped it!  (I do *NOT* want xcopy to run!)

#### This works...

```cmd
Echo Echo F ^| Xcopy /Y '%~1' '%~2' >>%log%
```

If I `Echo` that line specifically as shown above, I get no error on the console and I still get my output, and xcopy isn't ran. Is it simply because the pipeline is unescapable, and thus breaking `CMD` out of the STDOUT and truly invoking this command?

I'm using it inside a function where `args` 1 and 2 are files, but am using single quotes for the strings since I know the double quotes will break the `<nul set/p` text output approach.

#### More questioning around this...

Is it because I'm executing the `set /p` inside a `()` block?  I've tried `|`, `^|`, and `^^|` inside the double quotes and I still get the error as though `|` is not being escaped.  I even get the error when I use `2>&1` to force the output of `STDERR` to the log file!  (Since I do not care that the command doesn't run, I'm willing to output `STDERR` to log or `nul` - I successfully run it later in the subroutine - this is just a line out to the log for clarity on what was ran to copy the files)

What's weirder still - with both `|` and `^|` I see `^^|` in the log output.  Why is it appending TWO (2) `^` to the log in the `set /p`?  With `^^|`, I see `^^^^|` in the log output and still get the `Invalid Parameters` error! Do I need three (3) `^` to properly escape?

I must be missing something simple, or chalk this up to other problems inherent with the Pipeline...

#### Edit:

If I'm using a Pipeline, should I also send the Command's output to nul inside the `()` block like below, or will this simply be overruled by the outer redirect to `%log%`?  I have to assume the `|` will not be escaped no matter what I do, and when I execute the `<nul set /p` line to output the line, 2>&1 inside the `set /p` command, the `STDERR` would at least be sent to the logfile or `nul` depending on how it interprets...

```cmd
<nul (set /p "Lineout=Echo F ^| Xcopy /Y '%~1' '%~2' >nul 2>&1") >>%log%
```

I want to assume the Pipeline is simply executing the command to the right of it inside the block, and the redirect external to the block is working as one would expect for any code block in `()`

Comment: `set /p` is still, ultimately, a `set` command. You need an `=` sign for there to not be a syntax error. That said, I'm not sure what you're even trying to accomplish with the `<nul set /p` approach unless you're trying to append the entire output of the `xcopy` command onto a single line in `%log%`. Also, single quotes have no meaning in batch, so `xcopy` isn't happy about that either.

Comment: @SomethingDark, The actual purpose is literally to just output the line of the command to the log file - that's all this is for - hence my confusion - why is it attempting to _use_ xcopy inside of the set command even with `|` escaped?  I'm not wanting it to _run_ xcopy, but I know it _is_ and I'm not sure why.  If I remove the `|` completely, it works just fine and the CMD interpreter doesn't attempt to _run_ xcopy.  The reason for single quotes is because CMD very much hates having double quotes inside double quotes as used to encase the set command, and creates a syntax error.

Comment: I'm unsure if the `xcopy` command is your actual problem or if you chose it just randomly to demonstrate your escaping problem. If it's the first, note the `/-i` switch (`xcopy /?`) Btw: `<nul (set /p "Lineout=Echo F | Xcopy /Y '%~1' '%~2'")` outputs the exact thing you stated as "purpose". (no escaping needed due to proper quoting)

Comment: @Stephan, the xcopy example is currently the only command in which I'm also using `Echo text |` prior - in some cases the pipeline is not needed because I do not have to specify it's a file to xcopy.  (The use case here is specifically to write the output of the command to the log file).

Comment: `Echo F | Xcopy /Y '%~1' '%~2'"` without literally interpreted `^` is not a problem, but `<nul (set /p "LineOut=:RoutineName %*")>>%log%` could not work depending on which argument strings are passed to the batch file respectively subroutine. `%*` expands always to all the arguments after the batch file name , even on `shift` was used before. `%*` references the string which `cmd.exe` finally split up into argument strings. `%~*` does not exist. Run in a command prompt window `call /?` for detailed help on how argument strings can be referenced in a batch file.

Comment: `"LineOut=:RoutineName %*"` does not work if the passed argument strings are enclosed in `"` because of containing a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~``. The first `"` in the argument strings marks now the end of the second argument string for command `set` and everything else up to next `"` is now passed as a not double quoted argument string by `cmd.exe`. There must be considered that `cmd.exe` does not first recognize that the command `set` should be executed. It first parses the command line with `&|<>` having a special meaning on not being inside `"..."`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer to "Does the set /p command force the CMD interpreter to evaluate a Pipeline, even if it's escaped? Is it possible to avoid this?" is "Yes, on condition."

As mentioned in a comment by @Mofi, the initial use of `<nul (set /p "lineOut=Echo F | Xcopy /Y '%~1' '%~2'")>>%log%` ***works as expected***. . .

What isn't taken into account in how I asked the question initially (because I thought it would not matter) is whether or not the string `Echo F | XCopy /Y '%~1' '%~2'` is interpreted the same way when it's sent as another argument for another routine when a specific use-case is handled.

I had made the assumption that these two examples of code are equivalent - they are NOT.

```cmd
REM Works as expected where '%~1' and '%~2' are file paths enclosed in a double quote line to be sent to a file.
<nul (set /p "lineOut=Echo F | Xcopy /Y '%~1' '%~2'")>>%log%

REM Does NOT work where %* contains the string listed above:
<nul (set /p "lineOut=:RoutineName %*")>>%log%
```

The use-case scenario which I thought would be considered equivalent when I was first testing is shown below.  It wasn't until much more testing that I isolated the %* as being the largest contributing factor.

As @Mofi stated in another comment, this use of `%*` fails because the `|` (as well as other operators - `&<>`) will be interpreted directly because they're stripped out of the `" string "` context and cannot be interpreted as a string.

```cmd
REM Does NOT work - the CMD Interpreter fails to ignore the pipeline when using this approach.
Call :WriteOut "Echo F | Xcopy /Y '%~1' '%~2'" %log% "Yes"

:WriteOut [Verbiage] [Log File] [To Log?]

REM This is the line which I thought compared Apples to Apples.  It does NOT!
<nul (set /p "lineOut=:WriteOut %*") >>%log%

REM This line worked fine
<nul (set /p "lineOut=%~1")

REM this line also worked fine
if not "%~3"=="" (
  <nul (set /p "lineOut=%~1")>>%log%
)
```

I've found if I use another parameter as needed, I can effectively get this to output to the log correctly with no errors:

```cmd
REM with Parameter 4, we have success.
Call :WriteOut "Echo F | Xcopy /Y '%~1' '%~2'" %log% "Yes" "Yes"

:WriteOut [Verbiage] [Log File] [To Log?] [Lineout Contains Special Characters?]

If "%~4"=="" (
  <nul (set /p "lineOut=:WriteOut %*") >>%log%
) else (
  >>%log% Echo(:WriteOut %*
)

REM . . . code . . .
```

I could also do this as I have in the past (without realizing this also solved the problem for me before I ever had it)

```cmd
:WriteOut [Verbiage] [Log File] [To Log?] [Lineout Contains Special Characters?]
REM Break apart Args supplied, and send output safely to log file
For %%a in (%*) do (
  set /a argCnt+=1
  REM Assumes you have !cr! and !lf! defined appropriately previously
  <nul (set /p "lineOut=:WriteOut Arg!argCnt! = %%~a!cr!!lf!")>>%log)
)

REM . . . Code . . .
```